# Want to display in a profile that a particular contact is part of a smart group related to their membership type

Tags: civimember, profile, smartgroups

We have created a member dashboard in Drupal which displays a civicrm profile with civicrm membership details.  Since I could not display membership type in the profile, I created a smart group which automatically adds a contact to a particular group related to their membership type.

However,when the contact views their profile, it is not showing that they are part of a particular group even though the field is publicly listed.  I saw a post here
https://forum.civicrm.org/index.php?topic=34060.0
which says its not possible.  If so , is there any other way that I can display that the contact membership type in a profile listing?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Drupal, why not make a Views Block showing membership status/type and put this somewhere eg /user?

I understand I am not answering the OP of 'how to show a Smart Group in a profile' but am trying to answer a more generic question "how can i show a user their membership type"

You may find a downloadable view that already does this in our [Treasure Trove](https://www.fuzion.co.nz/treasure-trove) eg [this one](https://www.fuzion.co.nz/blogs/showing-user-their-membership-status-using-views-block)

Comment: Thank you Pete.  I will probably look into Drupal views if there is no other way to do this through CiviCRM

Comment: Sure. Views just offers so much more flexibility than anything you can do with civicrm without getting tied in to customising templates etc

Comment: How did you go Vish - it is good to report back and mark Answers as Accepted or answer it yourself